# Как разделить переменную в bash

Tags: bash

У меня есть переменная $form, которая состоит из трёх частей, разделенных знаком | (например Test1|Test2|Test3)
Как записать эти три части каждую в свою переменную (например Test1 будет в переменной form1, Test2 в form2 и т.д.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

запишем в переменную строку

```
form="Test1|Test2|Test3"
```

теперь поделим по разделителю

```
IFS=\| read form1 form2 form3 <<< $form
```

готово.

Слеш там потому, что пайп.

Больше вариантов - https://linuxhint.com/bash_split_examples/

Comment: Не работает, просто записывает все через пробел в переменную form1

Comment: О, интересно, а IFS потом возвращать не нужно?

Comment: нет, не нужно. Это локальное изменение. Если код не работает, то возможно это не bash/zsh